# Distance search very slow with innodb compare to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb, distance, myisam

I have a simple SELECT mysql request for ordering the users by distance, like this :

```
SELECT 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(48.85980226) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians
( longitude ) - radians(2.29202271) ) + sin( radians(48.85980226) ) * sin( radians( latitude
 ) ) ) ) AS distance,           
id FROM `users` 
HAVING distance <= '100' 
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

I got about 50.000 users in my database (MySql 5.7).
When I set my table to MyISAM, request speed is reasonable, about 0.2s; but if I turn the engine to innodb, it takes about 8s ! 
I really need to use innodb because datas are very offtenly write&read (MyISAM causing lot's of *"myisam waiting for table level lock"*).
Any idea of how to optimize the speed for that query?
Thanks !

(sorry for my english)

**EDIT2** : I change the type of the coordonates, from DECIMAL to FLOAT, and the query is a little faster : 5s insteed of 8s...

**Edit3** (from comment, with bounding box)

```
SELECT  ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(48.85980226) ) *
        cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians ( longitude ) -
           radians(2.29202271) ) + sin( radians(48.85980226) ) *
            sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance,
        uid
    FROM  users
    WHERE  longitude between 0.089154409442052 AND 4.4948910105579
      AND  latitude between 47.410526897681 AND 50.309077622319
    HAVING  distance <= '100'
    ORDER BY  distance ASC
```

**Edit 4** : Here is my table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `users` 
( `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`uid` varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
`token` varchar(70) NOT NULL, 
`last_connection` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`longitude` float NOT NULL, 
`latitude` float NOT NULL, 
`presentation` text NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
KEY `uid` (`uid`), 
KEY `uid_token` (`uid`,`token`), 
KEY `longitude` (`longitude`), 
KEY `latitude` (`latitude`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53004 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The field `last_connection` is updated very frequently. The more users are online, the more the query going slower... I guess because of the updates the row is locked temporary and the query going slow... :/
When using MyISAM, the search query is OK, but the updates ones going slow (whaiting for lock)

**EDIT 5** 
here is my update query :

```
UPDATE `users` SET `last_connection` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `uid` = 'XXXX';
```

I changed it and added a limit 1 :

```
UPDATE `users` SET `last_connection` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `uid` = 'XXXX' LIMIT 1;
```

This seems to be faster. I need to wait for more users to be connected to check if the difference is big or not

Comment: Your query is always going to be slow. You're running mathematical calculations on every record in your table for every request this way. You should be using MySQL's spatial extensions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) instead, which allow them to process stuff more efficiently.

Comment: ok I will check this

Comment: How about making NodeJS or Go app that will keep users table in memory and will do calculation by request without touching database and will stream result by streaming via net socket?

Comment: @Guillaume read this: https://www.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL , seems like explains how to solve Your issue.

Comment: @num8er I tryied to use a PROCEDURE, but it does not change the speed :/

Answer (score 0):

Database engine does calculation on every row.

So how about having already calculated values stored as variable?

```
SET @cos_point1 = cos(radians(48.85980226));

SET @rad_point1 = radians(2.29202271);

SET @sin_point1 = sin(radians(48.85980226));

SELECT 
( 6371 * acos( @cos_point1 * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians
( longitude ) - @rad_point1 ) + @sin_point1 * sin( radians( latitude
 ) ) ) ) AS distance,           
id FROM `users` 
HAVING distance <= 100
ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Also I've an idea!

Try this:

1) Create table `users_geodata` of type Memory (because real data will be in `users` table, let's use fastest engine for temporary table):

```
CREATE TABLE `users_geodata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latitude` float NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=Memory;
```

2) Schedule synchronization that does this:

```
REPLACE INTO users_geodata 
SELECT id, latitude, longitude FROM users
```

3) Run Your query:

```
SELECT 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(48.85980226) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians
( longitude ) - radians(2.29202271) ) + sin( radians(48.85980226) ) * sin( radians( latitude
 ) ) ) ) AS distance,           
id FROM `users_geodata` 
HAVING distance <= 100 
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: on local, this is really faster. But on production server, it is the same. Maybe a problem with my configuration...

Comment: @Guillaume I know it's dumb, but how You connect to database? Could it be because of network connection? Actually if it's production server so it can cause loads, because there is difference between: production server that has loads and local server that have only one requester.

Comment: @Guillaume I've an idea! (: how about just move lat, lon to another table: users_geodata ?

Comment: yes I was thinking about it, put the coordonate in a MyISAM table and make a JOIN. I will mak some tests on that.

Comment: first test using InnoDB, then if not, so change it to MyISAM, cuz table locking is not beautiful thing (:

Comment: @Guillaume keep lon, lat in users, but have users_geodata table that engine=Memory for fastest results (;

Comment: @Guillaume, any luck? (:

Comment: no, speed don't change. But I changed the type of my latitude/longitude from DECIMAL to FLOAT, and the speed is a little better now : 5s insteed of 8s

Comment: @Guillaume even with users_geodata that has Memory engine?

Comment: yes, even with this engine. I edited my post. The problem is the rows of my table are always updated, to know if user is online or not. And I guess those updates causing some lock and make my query going slower...

Answer (score 0):

Since InnoDB and MyISAM have to do equivalent amounts of work, I suspect the real problem is in caching.  Check the values of these:

```
key_buffer_size
innodb_buffer_pool_size
```

and note how much RAM you have.

If you are using only InnoDB, check that the buffer_pool is about 70% of available RAM (for machines of 4GB or more).  [*More details*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-memory-allocation/)

The next step in speeding things up is to have a `WHERE` clause include a "bounding box", plus have `INDEX(latitude)` and `INDEX(longitude)`.  (There is no advantage in using a composite index.)

[*For huge lat/lng tables*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/latitudelongitude-indexing/).

**Using "covering" index**

Replace `KEY(latitude)` with `KEY(latitude, longitude, uid)` and `KEY(longitude)` with `KEY(longitude, latitude, uid)`.  These will be "covering", hence somewhat faster, and possibly less contentious.  (The Optimizer will pick between the two indexes based on statistics based on the values in the actual queries.)

Comment: here is my settings : 
key_buffer_size = 2097152000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2147483648
the server RAM : 2x 16384Mo

(I tryed to add the "bounding box" but it did not change anything )

Comment: For a mixed system with 16GB of RAM, I would up the buffer_pool to 5G.

Comment: Please provide the `SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the bounding box; I suspect there is a minor error.

Comment: here is my query : SELECT 
( 
6371 * acos( cos( radians(48.85980226) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians
( longitude ) - radians(2.29202271) ) + sin( radians(48.85980226) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) 
) AS distance,
uid FROM `users` 
WHERE 
longitude between 0.089154409442052 and 4.4948910105579 
AND latitude between 47.410526897681 and 50.309077622319
HAVING distance <= '100' 
ORDER BY distance ASC

Comment: Need the `CREATE TABLE`, too.

Comment: [_representation precisions_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices)

Comment: here it is : CREATE TABLE `users` 
( `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`uid` varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
`token` varchar(70) NOT NULL, 
`last_connection` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`longitude` float NOT NULL, 
`latitude` float NOT NULL, 
`presentation` text NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
KEY `uid` (`uid`), 
KEY `uid_token` (`uid`,`token`), 
KEY `longitude` (`longitude`), 
KEY `latitude` (`latitude`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53004 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: I edited my post. The field "last_connection" is updated many times, and the more users are online (means more updates), the more the query going slower. When using MyISAM, the problem inversed : search query is good, but update queries are locked

Comment: See my "covering" suggestion; it may help noticeably.